# What to do when you get a number number like 40182 or 15368 when you expect a date?

Tags: r, excel, date

In some instances you are working with dates, when you suddenly get numbers that look like 40182 or 15368. This can for example happen when you import data from Excel, but also within values that you encounter with operations in R. The values look as following:

```
date1 <- 40182
date2 <- 15368
```

However, in the context of the data we would expect date values (e.g. `2011-12-16`). Why are the dates displayed like this?

Comment: the guesses in the answer below are pretty good, but I wouldn't mind some more context.  Guessing with data is scary.  (**edit**: I see that you've answered your own question.  That's fine, but I still think the question needs more context in order to be useful to anyone else ...)

Comment: This is not a personal wiki.

Comment: @BenBolker As you suggested I have added a little more context to it. I spent some time searching for the answer and when I found it I thought I might share it as well. Hopefully somebody else will take a little advantage of this Q&A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This are valid date values, but the source might not be clear. In the above cases you convert the dates as following:

```
# the value comes from Excel
as.Date(40182,origin="1899-12-30")

# the value comes from R but put in number format
as.Date(15368,origin="1970-01-01")
```